# Spark. Different casing in files

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

Let's say I have json file of this content. Both objects have different casing (first one have "location", while second have "Location"). This causes error in spark when reading.

```
{"data": [
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "properties": {
      "extendedProperties": {
        "location": "westeurope"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "properties": {
      "extendedProperties": {
        "Location": "westeurope"
      }
    }
  }
]}
```

I can use `spark.sql.caseSensitive` option to read successfully. However, schema will have two different columns: "location" and "Location". It would cause problems when writing to delta table. I can't hardcode solution like: make "Location" lowercase. Because I don't control source files and it could cause problems in future because schema will change.

Comment: if you control your Spark then `df.withColumn("location", expr("coalesce(location, Location)").drop("Location")`